# How to develop a java script image editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, prototypejs

I'd like to create a java-script image editor.

We have an ability to drag and drop multiple images to our editor and then  with following properties,

1. Undo
2. Redo
3. Move upward position
4. Move backward position
5. Drag and Drop
6. Change background color

Finally create and save a single image with all our modifications.

I'd like to go with jquery/ prototype library to develop the same. But I'm not sure about my selection and want to know is there any other library to complete my requirement. Please suggest a better one if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the choice of a library to do your coding is not the case here. Use any you are comfortable with. I would only wonder how such editor should be made. If the requirements about the app will not change, you can easily create your editor using html and css or svg ([raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) js, [adobe snap](http://snapsvg.io/) js). If you consider adding further image processing in the future than canvas rendering is your way to go ([example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas))

Also if you plan to add image resizing and rotating but need to support older browsers (like IE8 or IE7) you should use raphael with svg.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try these and update you my comments